# MYSQL select the lastest time of each date

Tags: mysql, datetime, distinct, greatest-n-per-group

Hi I have a mysql table and it contained something like this

```
HISTORY
===================
2013-07-01 16:23:43
2013-07-01 17:32:11
2013-07-01 20:44:22
2013-07-02 23:65:12
2013-07-03 10:23:32
2013:07-03 12:54:02
and etc........
```

for example the first three row are 2013-07-01 16:23:43,  2013-07-01 17:32:11, and
2013-07-01 20:44:22 and the lastest date in this history is 2013-07-01 20:44:22

So what I really want is.. Is there any way that I could make a selection that have a result like this

```
HISTORY
===================
2013-07-01 20:44:22
2013-07-02 23:65:12
2013:07-03 12:54:02
etc....
```

Thank You

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: I added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag, because this general type of question about SQL has been answered many times on StackOverflow.  Follow that tag for ideas on similar solutions.

Comment: In the 4 row of your input your minute field is showing value 65... `2013-07-02 23:65:12`.. :P

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO well thank you for your warning sir. I'm pretty new here. next if I'm asking question I'll follow your advice.

Comment: @Meherzad didn't' noticed that before. thanks for reminded me, it's pretty obvious that i write that manually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this query

```
select date(history) as dat,
max(history)
from table1
group by dat
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/236cb/1)**

```
|                         DAT |                MAX(HISTORY) |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| July, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 | July, 01 2013 20:44:22+0000 |
| July, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000 | July, 02 2013 23:59:12+0000 |
| July, 03 2013 00:00:00+0000 | July, 03 2013 12:54:02+0000 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be like that;

```
select Max(history) as MyMaxTimeForADay from MyTime t1 group by Date(t1.history);
```

you can see how is work at this link : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/12be2/2/0